# integral over the surface of a three-dimensional sphere of unit radius

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics, surface-integrals

Compute the following integral over the surface of a three-dimensional sphere of unit radius: $$ I(k)=\int_{|r|=1} dS e^{ik*r}$$ Here dS denotes the area of a differentially small surface element $$ k=(k_{x}, k_{y}, k_{z})$$ is a given three-dimensional vector. the vector $$r=(x,y,z) $$ and the scalar product $$k*r=(x*k_{x}, x*k_{y}, x*k_{z})$$

[image: this is what i did]

Comment: i tried going in the spherical coordinates and used r=1 but couldn't find the ans

Comment: Put info about your personal trials in the question itself not in the comments

Comment: So, what is the question actually?

Comment: we have to integrate over a unit sphere the given complex function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a sphere, it is easiest to invoke spherical coordinates to tackle a problem like this. In such a case, the area element on a surface of radius $r$ is given by $$dS=r^2
\sin\theta d\theta d\phi,$$ where $\theta$ runs from $0$ to $\pi$ and $\phi$ runs over $0$ to $2\pi$. This is also bound to the surface $r=1$ so that we only have $dS=\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$.

At this point I would note that your scalar product $\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}$ should be $\textit{scalar}$ rather than a vector. If $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)$, then $$\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}=k_xx+k_yy+k_zz.$$

Using spherical coordinates, this becomes
$$\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}=k_xr\sin\theta\cos\phi+k_yr\sin\theta\sin\phi+k_zr\cos\theta.$$

We can note that in the $\mathbf{k}$-dependence, there is rotational symmetry. You can see this from the definition of the scalar product, $\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}=|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{r}|\cos\theta$. So let's first rotate such that the $\mathbf{k}$ vector is pointing along the $z$-axis (such that $k_x=0$, $k_y=0$, $k_z=K=|\mathbf{k}$|).

Plugging this into the integral, and recalling that on the surface $r=|\mathbf{r}|=1$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
I(k)&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{i(k_xr\sin\theta\cos\phi+k_yr\sin\theta\sin\phi+k_zr\cos\theta)}\sin\theta d\theta d\phi,\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{iK\cos\theta}\sin\theta d\theta d\phi.
\end{align}
$$
The integral over $\phi$ is immediately doable,

$$
I(k)=2\pi\int_0^\pi e^{iK\cos\theta}\sin\theta d\theta.
$$
Then one should note that
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}e^{iK\cos\theta}=-i\sin\theta Ke^{iK\cos\theta},
$$ hence
$$
\begin{align}
I(k)&=2\pi\int_0^\pi e^{iK\cos\theta}\sin\theta d\theta,\\
&=-\frac{2\pi}{iK}\int_0^\pi \frac{d}{d\theta}\left(e^{iK\cos\theta}\right)d\theta,\\
&=-\frac{2\pi}{iK}\left(e^{iK\cos\pi}-e^{iK\cos 0}\right),\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{iK}\left(e^{iK}-e^{-iK}\right),\\
&=\frac{4\pi}{K}\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{iK}-e^{-iK}\right),\\
&=\frac{4\pi}{K}\sin K,\\
&=4\pi\frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2}\right)}{\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2}},
\end{align}
$$
where in the above I have used the fundamental theorem of calculus and the definition of the sine function in terms of the exponential.

Comment: Shorter version: orient so $\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}=kr\cos\theta=k\cos\theta$. No need to think about $k_x$ etc.

Comment: @J.G. of course! Thank you for this shortcut. I had intended on showing the "trick" of using the rotational freedom in momentum space to simplify the problem (as it is quite a versatile method) but this gets there clearly and concisely.